# Negotiation with car insurance damage adjuster

Tags: car-insurance

Another driver backed into and damaged my car. I have filed the claim with the other driver’s insurance. As the standard protocol, they will come, access the damage and write me a check for the estimated repair cost.

If the reimbursement stops at that, I do not find it fair. Because of the accident, I had to take a half day vacation from my work (lost wages). I feel disoriented and I am not able to focus on anything(after accident shock) even though I feel fine physically.

Also, if I do decide to fix my car, I would have to drop it to the repair shop, pick it up at later day, rental cost and all the hassle in between. Worst part is my insurance premium may go up because they may see me as accident prone, even though this accident was not my fault.

The questions is, how do I negotiate with the insurance adjuster so that I am fairly compensated for the hassle on top of the repair cost?

Comment: Does your insurance plan include no-fault or Personal Injury Protection (PIP)? Does the at-fault driver have Bodily Injury Liability coverage? Does the at-fault driver *have* sufficient coverage? What state did this happen in? This is also off-topic I suspect, but lots of variables will determine what you can recoup. Really you need to speak to your policyholder about what your policy covers, and I'm not sure how to determine what the other driver's policy covers. You might need to contact a personal injury attorney, if the lost wages are significant.

Comment: Even though the other insurance company is accepting responsibility, you can/should still contact your insurance company. They will negotiate on your behalf.

Comment: Consider also to mention to the other driver's insurance adjuster if you are unhappy with the result, that it is in your interest to consult an attorney, as CMosychuk suggested. Your losses are tangible and should not be dismissed by the adjuster.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can or even will need to.  The insurance companies have a pretty good idea what a realistic price is going to be to repair your car.  If you really disagreed with what they come up with, you can get your own estimates and try to argue that way, but I don't know how far that would take you, since they likely have shops they partner with in your area and the adjuster is an expect at determining damages; its what they do for a living.  If you really don't like their number, you can always submit to your insurance company.  Then you'll be dealing with them, and they'll deal with the other insurer.

Ask for a rental; that's a perfectly reasonable request and I'd be surprised if they didn't cover one.  It should be comparable to your car, although I wouldn't try and get a BMW or something.  Think same class (sedan, SUV).

I also would be surprised if your insurer raised your rates for something which was not your fault.  Its possible I suppose, but your insurance probably requires you to report all accidents anyway, and they might have a clause saying they can drop you or deny coverage if you fail to.  You may have accident forgiveness too, its a pretty popular thing to be just included now, unless you have a really barebones insurer.  Your best bet is to call them and let them know what's going on, and that you're dealing with the other insurance yourself (for now).

> I had to take a half day vacation from my work (lost wages). I feel
>   disoriented and I am not able to focus on anything(after accident
>   shock) even though I feel fine physically.

I think no one is going to care about this stuff.  You're not injured, you didn't lose wages (unless your in CA, vacation days aren't considered wages), and it doesn't sound like the accident was that bad (I don't get the impression you believe your car was totaled).  Accidents are part of owning a car.  You need to deal with it and move on; there are much worse things in life.  Be glad you're not hurt.